# Add <li> to first and end of all lines of text file with batch script?

Tags: text, batch-file, addition

First thanks for the attention. 
I need batch script to add `<li>`  to beginning and end all lines of text file
I use.

```
@echo off
set  h=<l>
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (input.txt) do (
set /a N+=1
echo %h%^%%a^a>>output.txt
)
```

But its only works when h=any text;
when h=`<li>` it
doesn't work !!
please help me.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
set h=^<l^>
```

The `^` is an escape character. This is needed, because `<` and `>` are special characters. they are used in CMD to redirect input and output from or to a file.

Also, there are two `^` characters in the last line, that may cause you trouble. The first will probably escape the first `%` sign of `%%a`, which I think is not what you meant to do.

Comment: It should be rather `set "h=^<l^>"` so carets do not get stripped on definition and may actually escape `<>` later (in echo)

Comment: thanks I try this and works          @echo off
set h=^<li
set g=^>
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (input.txt) do (
set /a N+=1
echo ^%h%^%g%%%a^%h%^%g%>>output.txt
)

Comment: thakns GolezTrol this was very useful

Comment: @wmz Have you tried it? It will add the quotes to %h%, adding them to the output.

Comment: No it won't. It quotes the expression, not the value itself (note the positiion of first `"`)